# Data coming but not showing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching some data from the backend and data is fetched without any errors, but the problem is that before the data is fetched, the HTML part is getting loaded and that's why data is not showing on the page.
This may be a simple problem, but as a beginner, I don't know how to resolve this.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import HospitalCard from "../components/HospitalCard";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 2vh 5vw;
  margin: auto;
`;

function Home() {
  const nothing = <div>Nothing to show</div>;

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [Hospitals, setHospitals] = useState([]);

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(false);

  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState("");

  const getSearchValue = (e) => {
    setSearchItem(e);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMount = true;
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/search").then((response) => {
      if (isMount) {
        const hdata = response.data;
        setHospitals(hdata);
        console.log(hdata);
        console.log(Hospitals);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      isMount = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFiltered(true);
    var filteredHospitals = Hospitals.filter(function (el) {
      console.log(el.city);
      return (
        el.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase().trim()) ||
        el.hospitalname
          .toLowerCase()
          .trim()
          .includes(searchItem.toLowerCase().trim()) ||
        el.state.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase().trim())
      );
    });
    setData(filteredHospitals);
  }, [searchItem]);

  console.log(Hospitals);
  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar style={{ margin: "auto" }} getSearchValue={getSearchValue} />
      <Container>
        {filtered
          ? data
            ? data.map((hospital) => {
                return (
                  <HospitalCard
                    key={hospital.mobilenumber}
                    hospital={hospital}
                  />
                );
              })
            : nothing
          : Hospitals.map((hospital) => {
              return (
                <HospitalCard key={hospital.mobilenumber} hospital={hospital} />
              );
            })}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: log the values of `filtered`, `data` before returning the JSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should simplify the way you handle filtering by removing the `filtered` flag and using an array to store the data to display in both cases.

1. Create a `filteredHospitals` state to contain the data to be displayed
2. When filtering update the data of this value
3. Use conditional rendering to display the data if present

Finally, i think that you should change your `getSearchValue` code to `setSearchItem(e.target.value)` (You were using `setSearchItem(e)`).
The code of the `SearchBar` component is not included but I guess that the `e` parameter refers to the on change event object.

```
function Home() {
  const [Hospitals, setHospitals] = useState([]);
  const [filteredHospitals, setFilteredHospitals] = useState([]);

  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState('');

  const getSearchValue = (e) => {
    setSearchItem(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMount = true;
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/search').then((response) => {
      if (isMount) {
        const hdata = response.data;
        setHospitals(hdata);
        setFilteredHospitals(hdata);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      isMount = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    var filteredHospitals = Hospitals.filter(function (el) {
      console.log(el.city);
      return (
        el.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase().trim()) ||
        el.hospitalname
          .toLowerCase()
          .trim()
          .includes(searchItem.toLowerCase().trim()) ||
        el.state.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase().trim())
      );
    });
    setFilteredHospitals(filteredHospitals);
  }, [searchItem]);

  console.log(Hospitals);

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar style={{ margin: 'auto' }} getSearchValue={getSearchValue} />
      <Container>
        {filteredHospitals && filteredHospitals.length > 0 ? filteredHospitals.map((hospital) => {
                return (
                  <HospitalCard
                    key={hospital.mobilenumber}
                    hospital={hospital}
                  />
                );
              }) : 'No data...'}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use conditional render. Read this guide https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

```
{filtered != undefined ? filtered?data?data.map((hospital) => {
                return <HospitalCard key={hospital.mobilenumber} hospital={hospital}/>
            }):nothing:Hospitals.map((hospital) => {
                return <HospitalCard key={hospital.mobilenumber} hospital={hospital}/>
            }) }
```